# split a string at every position c#

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm writing a program for a barcodescanner in `C# .NET 3.5`. When I scan the barcode I get an `string` with just numbers and I want that string to split at every number and put each number into an `int array`, but I can´t figure out how. Does someone of you know how to do that?

Comment: You haven´t tried out much, do you? Shouldn´t be that hard to google this. Apart from this please provide some sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] array = "1234567890".ToCharArray().Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

You can omit method invocation of `ToCharArray` as `string` is already collection of chars :)

Comment: No need for `ToCharArray` here - `string` already implements `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to convert a `char` into a `integer`

```
char digit = '0';

int result = (int)char.GetNumericValue(digit);
int result = ((int)digit) - 48;
int result = digit - '0'; //fastest approach
int result = int.Parse(digit.ToString());
int result = Convert.ToInt32(digit.ToString());
int result = digit & 0x0f;
```

so if you want the most performant approach then use

```
string input = "123";
int[] result = input.Select(x => x - '0').ToArray();
```